# Authorization failure on remote build trigger in Jenkins 2.387

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, authorization, jenkins-plugins

I created a pipeline job that needs to be triggered if there are any changes in 2 other repositories in GitHub. Lets call this one `PipelineJob`.
I have this job with a parameter `FullBuild='True'` set as a string and I want to trigger this job with this parameter whenever one of the repositories has changes.

For the first job I'm using a Freestyle project that has a post build action, which polls `repo1` for changes and builds `PipelineJob` with the `FullBuild` parameter set to `False`

For the second job as the post build action does not provide a parametrized build, I had to switch to a shell command which curls the Jenkins API and triggers a build with parameters, but this fails tremendously on all attempts.

I'm either getting a `403 invalid crumb` or Authentication required

```
curl -L --user Automation:119c95933d29011ca4e758fb5007cee5a1 'https://my.private.domain/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,":",//crumb)'
<html><head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;url=/login?from=%2FcrumbIssuer%2Fapi%2Fxml%3Fxpath%3Dconcat%28%2F%2FcrumbRequestField%2C%22%3A%22%2C%2F%2Fcrumb%29'/><script>window.location.replace('/login?from=%2FcrumbIssuer%2Fapi%2Fxml%3Fxpath%3Dconcat%28%2F%2FcrumbRequestField%2C%22%3A%22%2C%2F%2Fcrumb%29');</script></head><body style='background-color:white; color:white;'>


Authentication required
<!--
-->

</body></html>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            


curl -L -X POST "http://my.private.domain/job/PipelineJob/buildWithParameters?FullBuild=True" --user 'Automation:119c95933d29011ca4e758fb5007cee5a1'
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 403 No valid crumb was included in the request</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 403 No valid crumb was included in the request</h2>
<table>
<tr><th>URI:</th><td>/job/Staging-aws-tests/buildWithParameters</td></tr>
<tr><th>STATUS:</th><td>403</td></tr>
<tr><th>MESSAGE:</th><td>No valid crumb was included in the request</td></tr>
<tr><th>SERVLET:</th><td>Stapler</td></tr>
</table>
<hr/><a href="https://eclipse.org/jetty">Powered by Jetty:// 10.0.13</a><hr/>

</body>
</html>
```

This jenkins instance is behind a reverse proxy, inside a docker container. I've tried using the Strict Crumb Issuer plugin and disabling session checking, I've tired creating a new user with a new token, same result.

I'm not sure what I'm hitting, but any assistance is much appreciated.